# Stripe: Send money to a Connected Account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment-gateway, stripe-payments, payment-processing, stripe-connect

I am building an application that allows (potentially anonymous) users to send money to a third-party.  It is a requirement that the money go directly and not touch the app's account.  Stripe's Connect platform seems to allow this, by the third-party connecting an account: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees

The "Charge Directly" option seems to do as desired.  However, my current implementation seems to be sending the money to my platform's account instead of the third-party connected account.  I am using Ruby, so this format applies:

```
Stripe.api_key = PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY
Stripe::Charge.create({
  :amount => 1000,
  :currency => "usd",
  :source => {TOKEN}
}, {:stripe_account => CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID})
```

The `TOKEN` is obtained via Stripe.js from the user inputting their credit card information.  I have substituted the `PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY` variable for the secret key obtained in my platform's Stripe account under API keys.  I have stored the third-party's `user_id` from when they connected their account via Stripe Connect, which I input for `CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID`.

As the payments are showing up in my platform's dashboard under 'Payments', I clearly have some keys mixed up.  Can anyone point me in the right direction for which keys go where?  Thank you!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The `Stripe.api_key` value should be the connected account's `access_token`.  Stripe's example code incorrectly labels it as PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY.

Comment: Since he's passing the stripe_account header it should be the platform's secret key

Answer (score 3):

If you're seeing it in your dashboard either:

1) the version of the Stripe library you're using is not new enough to support the Stripe-Account header.

2) You're passing a null as the connected account id

3) You're passing your own account id as the connected account id.

Comment: None of these were the case.  Using the connected account's access_token was the solution.